# How to solved problem SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: {table_name} (SQL: select * from {table_name}) in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, testing

I have a problem when I want to `feature` test my laravel project, I get this error:

```
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: {table_name} (SQL: select * from {table_name})

  at G:\Project\HamtaNew\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:671
    667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    670|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 671|             throw new QueryException(
    672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673|             );
    674|         }
    675|
```

My laravel version is 7,

And one error point I get is related to a table that I did not use at all in the query !!

anybody can help me?

Comment: please share you query or migration that cause this error

Comment: We'll need more detail. There's many reasons why laravel can choose to select from tables you don't include, eager loading for example, or loading metadata from information_schema etc

Comment: @OMR, that {table_name} has nothing related to the part I want to test.

Comment: ok, have setup your file phpunit.xml?

Comment: It's True, my phpunit.xml file was set to sqlite. thanks guys.